# Getting value from user

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA. I have recorded macros but haven't written any code myself. I am attempting to get input from a user and place it into a cell.

My attempted code is below.

```
Sub test ()
Dim myvar as string 
myvar = "testname"
'Put item in cell
End sub
```

Comment: There are many sites dedicated to teaching how to code in vba.  Stack Overflow is not one of those.  SO is a place to get help with code that has errors.

Comment: You've told us a story ("my code doesn't work"), but this site is for asking questions ("how do I get results from a user and place it in a cell?"). Though, in this case, you properly needed to show you've done a basic search for the answer first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code supplied below will get input from the end-user, place it into cell A1 in this example, and notify you that it was successful.

```
Sub Test() 'Declare Sub
    Dim InputValue As String 'Declare the string
    InputValue = InputBox("Enter text...") 'Get input from end user
    Range("A1").Value = InputValue 'Place input into cell A1
    MsgBox "Your input """ & InputValue & """ has been placed in cell A1" 'Message box indicate it was placed in A1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `inputbox`

```
Sub test ()
Dim myVar as string 
myVar = InputBox("Please, enter your name:","Name Info Required","testname")
'Put item in cell
ThisWorkBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value = myVar
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answers you got here, look into using `Application.InputBox` , this allows restriction of the Input provided by the user.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim myVar  As String

    myVar = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter text (as String)...", Type:=2)
    ' the rest is the same as the answers above
    Range("A1").Value = myVar

End Sub
```

To learn more about the options of `Application.InputBox` , read a little at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx)